# The object is not created

Tags: php, class, instantiation

I created a class named "Personnage" (character in french) which create a character for a game. But, when I create an instance of the class, an object, it doesn't work. My object is not created. I created a method named "salut()" (hi in french) which only contains an echo. When i call it, nothing appears. I also did a var_dump and print_r of the object but nothing appears. Here is the code :

Personnage.class.php :

```
<?php

class Personnage
{
//ATRIBUTS
private $_id;
private $_nom;
private $_degats;

//FONCTIONS
public function __construct(array $donnee)
{
    $this->hydrate($donnee);
}

public function hydrate(array $donnee)
{
    foreach($donnee as $key => $value)
    {
        $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
        if(method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
}

public function salut()
{
    echo 'SALUT';
}

public function attaquer(Personnage $adversaire)
{
    $adversaire->setDegats($adversaire->getDegats + 5);
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
    $manager = new PersonnagesManager($db);
    $manager->updateDegats($adversaire);
    $adversaire->mourrir();
}

public function mourrir()
{
    if($this->_degats >= 100)
    {
        $db2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
        $manager2 = new PersonnagesManager($db2);
        $manager2->delete($this);
    }
}

//SET
public function setId($id)
{
    if(is_int($id))
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }
}

public function setNom($nom)
{
    if(is_string($nom))
    {
        $this->_nom = $nom;
    }
}

public function setDegats($degats)
{
    if(is_int($degats) && $degats >= 0 && $degats <= 100)
    {
        $this->_degats = $degats;
    }
}


//GET
public function getId{ return $this->_id; }
public function getNom{ return $this->_nom; }
public function getDegats{ return $this->_degats; }
}

?>
```

test2.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

function chargerClasse($classe)
{
require $classe .'.class.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('chargerClasse');

 $name = 'Pat'
 $perso = new Personnage(array('nom' => $name));
 $perso->salut();
 var_dump($perso);
?>
```

My files are in the same folder. I didn't find the error, maybe will you ..? Thanks.

Comment: Turn `error_reporting` and `display_errors` on. Your class probably probably can't be found. Paste the class into `test2.php` -- does it work then?

Comment: Given that your file is `Personnage.class.php`, and you're trying `chargerClasse.class.php`, the require would be failing and aborting your script at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your class method declarations:

```
public function getId{ return $this->_id; }
public function getNom{ return $this->_nom; }
public function getDegats{ return $this->_degats; }
```

You are missing the parenthesis:

```
public function getId(){ return $this->_id; }
public function getNom(){ return $this->_nom; }
public function getDegats(){ return $this->_degats; }
```